# header(location:URL) does not work

Tags: php, redirect, header

I am retrieving data from a database to verify user credentials.
In case of a password mismatch, I wish to redirect the user to the login page.
However, this never happens. Instead, I am redirected to chat_main.php.

It works fine for all other cases (invalid email, valid email and password combination).

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("config/db_connect.php");
$usr=$_POST['email'];
$pwd=$_POST['password'];
$q="SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE email=\"$usr\"";
$info=mysql_query($q, $conn);
if(mysql_num_rows($info)!=1){
    header("Location: login.php?err=1");
}
else{
    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($info)){
        if($pwd!=$data['pwd']){
            header("Location: login.php?err=1");
        }
        $usr=$_SESSION['username']=$data['fname'];
        header("Location: chat_main.php?username=$usr");
    }
}
?>
```

Why is it behaving thus, and how can this be resolved?

Comment: Terminate the script after sending the `Location:` header.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add exit; after each header line, to make the script exit and actually process the header redirect. Otherwise, it will keep running and will hit the next header redirect..

Comment: It exits at the end of the code, yes. But it's hitting the next header, which nullifies the bad password redirect.

Comment: @Neal - yes, there is an issue here.  after he issues the first `header` the code continues to run and executes the second `header`.  This could also be solved by putting the second `header` inside an `else`.  But using `exit` is probably the best option.

Comment: @EricPetroelje the 2nd header shouldnt be hit!! it is inside of the else part!

Comment: @Neal - there is no `else` part - looking at the one inside the `while` loop

Comment: @EricPetroelje ahhh I see, your talking abt inside the while loop lol. **Now** I see.

Comment: @Neal - that's what you get for answering questions before having your morning coffee :)

Comment: @EricPetroelje ehhh I do not drink coffee :-P

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("config/db_connect.php");
$usr=$_POST['email'];
$pwd=$_POST['password'];
$q="SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE email=\"$usr\"";
$info=mysql_query($q, $conn);
if(mysql_num_rows($info)!=1){
header("Location: login.php?err=1");
exit;
}
else{
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($info)){
    if($pwd!=$data['pwd']){
        header("Location: login.php?err=1");
        exit;
    }
    $usr=$_SESSION['username']=$data['fname'];
    header("Location: chat_main.php?username=$usr");
    exit;
}
}
?>
```

Should work, because you have to terminate the script after sending header.

Comment: Care to explain what you improved/altered? Just "should work" doesn't provide much of a learning curve :)

Comment: @Disa **Y U GET RID OF NICE SPACING?**